# How to Use Web3 to Purchase ERC20 Token

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, erc20

I'm trying to implement a solidity  "purchase" function into web3. Ultimately, I want to have a button where a user would then have metamask open to send a fixed amount(1 ether for a simple example) to the smart contract in exchange for an ERC20 token. I've learned how to transfer tokens between two wallets, but now I'd like to go a step further and learn how to send Ether to receive an ERC20. This is the solidity "purchase" function I've been using:

```
function purchase(uint amount, uint tokens) public payable{
        require (msg.value >= amount * 1 ether, "You must pay at least 1 ether per token");
        balances[address (this)] -= tokens;
        balances[msg.sender] += tokens;
```

Right now I've been using this with an Onclick button in conjunction with metamask to transfer ERC20's:

```
async function transfer() {
        contract.methods.transfer("Address", "Token quantity").send({
        from: "Address"});
```

Do you have any tips on how to go about making this Ether to ERC20 function in JS? Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I've successfully used the Purchase function to send 1 Ether to my smart contract and receive an ERC20 token in return, although I'm only able to do this transaction with the address that I plug into the function:
```

async function purchase(){
            contract.methods.purchase("1","1").send({
    from: "Address", to: "Address", value: web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether") });

```
 How would any sender use this "Purchase" function to interact with the contract instead of just a specified address? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is insufficient information in the question. If you are asking how to call the purchase you have written in solidity then answer is as follow:

```
contract.methods.purchase("amount", "Token quantity").send({
    from: "Address", value: ("amount"*"Token quantity"(in wei)) });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I'm trying to call the Purchase function in Solidity. My goal is for a user to send 1 ether to the contract in return for 1 token. I'm making progress but I'm getting a failed transaction in metamask. I'm using:
```
async function purchase(){
            contract.methods.purchase("Address","1").send({
    from: "Address", to:"Address", value: web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether") });

```
"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:"

Comment: contract.methods.purchase("Address","1") => contract.methods.purchase(1, 1) 1st parameter in you contract is amount in uint not an address also tokens should be in uint. And also i think the contract is not written properly it should only have one param tokenAmount

Comment: If you want I can rewrite solidity code as well ! Just let me know

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll look at the parameters again. I have my ERC20 Interface with:
```
function purchase(uint amount, uint tokens) public payable;

```
Then in my contract I inherited it with:
```
function purchase(uint amount, uint tokens) public payable{
        require (msg.value >= amount * 1 ether, "You must pay at least 1 ether per token");
        balances[address (this)] -= tokens;
        balances[msg.sender] += tokens;
```
Yes, I would like to know how you would rewrite it, thanks!

Comment: `pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.7.0;
interface ERC20 {
    function mint(address reciever, uint256 value) external returns(bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns(bool);
}
 contract tokenSale {
    ERC20 Token;
        constructor(address tokenAddress) public {
        Token = ERC20(tokenAddress);
    }
    function purchase(uint _tokensAmount) public payable{ 
        require (msg.value >= _tokensAmount * 1 ether, "You must pay at least 1 ether per token"); 
        Token.mint(msg.sender, _tokensAmount)
    }
 }`

Comment: above one is tokenSale contract and you will have ur token address as well and pass it's address in this contractor with a mint function which will create new token and assign it to user who paid.

P.S sorry for the delay

Comment: Thank you!  I've successfully used the Purchase function to send 1 Ether to my smart contract and receive an ERC20 token , but I'm only able to do this transaction with an address that I plug into the function:

 ``` async function purchase(){ contract.methods.purchase("1","1").send({ from: "Address", to: "Address", value: web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether") }); 

``` How would any sender use this "Purchase" function to interact with the contract instead of just a specified address? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using metamask ? And How are you calling the purchase function is there a button or what ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! On my site I have a button that has the onclick binded to it so that when a user clicks on the button it calls the "purchase" function and opens metamask with the 1 ether requirement. I'm able to have it function but only when I have a specific address plugged into the "from:address". My problem is that I'm new to web3 and don't know how to have a sort of "msg.sender" equivalent, or a way to see a metamask user's address. Is there a way to tell the function to use current metamask address that's calling the function?

Comment: yes
`const Web3 = require("web3");
const ethEnabled = async () => {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    await window.ethereum.send('eth_requestAccounts');
    window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

if (!ethEnabled()) {
  alert("Please install MetaMask to use this dApp!");
}`
this would give you access ... If metamask is not connect to ur website this will promt it to connect

Comment: Once connected
`function getAccounts(callback) {
    web3.eth.getAccounts((error,result) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            callback(result);
        }
    });
}

getAccounts(function(result) {
    console.log(result[0]);
});`

use this You will have the connect address

and offcourse there is better way to make it look preatter but this would work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. After tinkering with the function I was able to call the "purchsae" function from any address! In the function's from address I plugged in "window.web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress" which worked!